# Bootstrap text not going below text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following list, I have tried everything to make it appear blew "Other phone number formats" but it always goes in front of it as shown in the image. What do I need to do for make it go below the text?

```
    <div class="row">
        <h4 th:text="|Other phone number formats for ${phoneNumber}|"></h4>

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Cras
                justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Dapibus
                ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Morbi
                leo risus</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Porta
                ac consectetur ac</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Vestibulum
                at eros</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put `<h4>` below `</ul>` ?

Comment: that will fix it that it will no longer be in front of it, but now <h4> is below it. I want the heading to show above the list

Comment: `<div class="row justify-content-center">` try that. And you can add some `col-xl-x` and `col-x` in addition to that, before the `</ul>` where `x` is a number of column, there are 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <h4 class="text-center" th:text="|Other phone number formats for ${phoneNumber}|"></h4>
          <div class="col-xl-12">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Cras
                    justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Dapibus
                    ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Morbi
                    leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Porta
                    ac consectetur ac</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${formatPhoneNumberNoDash}">Vestibulum
                    at eros</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

You can read more about it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Hope this helps.